# How to import many xslx files to R? (In one xlsx file there are many sheets and I need only one)

Tags: r, excel, csv

I'm new here and I don't know how this site works. If I make mistakes, sorry. 
Soooo I have 23 xlsx files with many sheets in them.

1. I have to create dataset which contains all of those files but with only one sheet. Columns and names of the sheets are the same.
2. I have to bind them by rows. 
   If anyone know how to do it, I will be very grateful.

   file.list <-list.files("D:/Profile/name/Desktop/Viss/foldername",pattern=".xlsx")

   df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
   Error: `path` does not exist:

   df <- rbindlist(df.list, idcol = "id")

I don't know where to put the extract of this one sheet and I don't know what to write in idcol="".

Comment: "I'm new here and I don't know how this site works. If I make mistakes, sorry." Rather than pre-emptively apologizing, the correct approach is to find out how the site works first. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach is correct, but you should use the full path in `file.list <-list.files("D:/Profile/name/Desktop/Viss/foldername",pattern=".xlsx", full.names=TRUE)`

---

EDIT: You should use pattern="\\.xlsx" in

```
list.files("D:/Profile/name/Desktop/Viss/foldername",pattern="\\.xlsx", full.names=TRUE)
```

---

EDIT2: You can always see **any** function help by running ? followed by your function name like `?rbindlist`, or in RStudio, pressing F1 on the function name. The `idcol` parameter should be TRUE or FALSE, in your case, FALSE probably.

- idcol 
  Generates an index column. Default (NULL) is not to. If idcol=TRUE then the column is auto named .id. Alternatively the column name can be directly provided, e.g., idcol = "id". If input is a named list, ids are generated using them, else using integer vector from 1 to length of input list. See examples.*

---

EDIT3 if you want to specify the sheet name you can use

```
lapply(file.list, function(x) read_excel(x, sheet="sheetname"))
```

Comment: Nope, it's not working and I don't know where to put name of the sheet that I need

Comment: do you still have Error: path does not exist? what does df.list contain? Also, see edits for \\.xlsx

Comment: it works, but there is 0 variables and 0 obs in df, maybe it's because those files have many sheets?

Comment: did you try the \\.xlsx pattern?

Comment: can you tell me what should I write in idcol= ? the name of the column?

Comment: how to extract one sheet from the file?

Comment: # A tibble: 0 x 0

Comment: what does `file.list[[1]]` say?

Comment: full path to one of the files from the folder

Comment: does this file contain data? if you want to specify which sheet you can see edit 3

Comment: Yes, this file contains data